# How do I inherit only the member functions in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Say I have a base class Base, and a derived class Derived.

```
class Base
{
public:
    void f1(void);
    ...
    int data1;
    ...
};

class Derived : Base
{
... add stuff here that's unique to Derived
};
```

How can Derived inherit only the functions (i.e., f1()) and NOT the data (i.e., data1) from Base?

Comment: What if your member methods utilize member variables?

Comment: Make the data `private`.

Comment: And use setter/getter methods.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: Make a base class with just the functions and then inherit it into the two different children.

Comment: Instead of leaving it on your shelf, actually _read_ your C++ book. It explains this within the first few pages.

Comment: @jamesdlin: It's a fairly conventional and commonplace thing to do, and has been for some three decades.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm just asking for clarification.  Does he just want to restrict *access* to the base class's data?  If so, then yes, making the base class's members private is the way to go (assuming that the base class can be modified).  Or maybe he doesn't want memory to be allocated for those data members at all and wants the base class to act as a pure interface.

Comment: Sadly, your downvotes have simply discouraged me from asking further questions -- I will now treat stack exchange as read-only -- message received. Lightness, you might consider making fewer assumptions about who has read what -- I've read two of Stroustrup's books; yes, the answer is "obvious" when you know how to phrase the question. Plonk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having attribute of a base class that is not needed in derived class is a hint for bad inheritance

in your case i assume you are going to have another derived class that needs those data members, otherwise it wouldnt make sense

then why not do something like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void f1(void);
    ...
};

class DerivedClass : Base
{
... add stuff here that's unique to Derived
};

class DerivedClass2 : Base
{ 
     public:
         int data1;
         ....
}
```

if you have more derived classes that needs those data member i suggest you to make separate base class, one for functions and one for data members.